# What are the differences between regular and Hardcore?

Tags: battleborn

You can play the battleborn campaign in four different modes: Normal, Normal Hardcore, Advanced and Advanced Hardcore. The difference between normal and advanced is the difficulty and the amount of loot you receive.

What changes does Hardcore apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to 2k support](http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/218453908-Here-Are-All-Of-Battleborn-s-Badass-Game-Modes),

> **Hardcore Mode:** There are no extra lives and you may gain extra loot and new unlockable content.